# Why do these results differ?

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, output

```
$Pre = If[FreeQ[#, Eps], #, 
    Module[{tmp}, 
     tmp = Evaluate[
        MatrixFunction[Function[Eps, #], {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]] // 
       FullSimplify;
     tmp /. {{a_, b_}, {0, a_}} -> a + Eps b /. {{a_, 0}, {b_, a_}} ->
        a + Eps b]] &;
Sign[a Eps]
Sign[a Eps] /. a -> 3
```

The two outputs are different by a factor of $a$: $a \varepsilon  \text{ sgn}'(0)$ versus $\varepsilon  \text{ sgn}'(0)$ What is going on? Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

First note, that `$Pre` without an attribute "HoldFirst" or "HoldAll" is the same as `$Post`.

Therefore,if you input: "Sign[a Eps] /. a -> 3". This will evaluate to Sign[3 Eps]. And this evaluates to Sign[Eps] because 3 is positive. Finally, what `$Pre` sees is therefore: Sign[Eps].

On the other hand, an input "Sign[a Eps]" will not change because the sign of a is not known. Therefore `$Pre` will be fed: "Sign[a Eps]"

Comment: How one can add those attributes?

Comment: The result not dependent on $a$ is desirable, by the way.

Comment: SetAttributes. Look it up in the help.